# How to rotate a 3D chart about its axes using the mouse in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: charts, rotation

I would like to rotate a Visual Studio 2010 Chart about its axes by moving the mouse over it (left button down).  I've found many examples in WPF, but none in WinForms.

I'm coding in Visual Basic.

Would someone please direct me to a tutorial or example code that will point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private Point mousePoint;

    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (mousePoint.IsEmpty)
                mousePoint = e.Location;
            else
            {

                int newy = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Rotation + (e.Location.X - mousePoint.X);
                if (newy < -180)
                    newy = -180;
                if (newy > 180)
                    newy = 180;

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Rotation = newy;

                newy = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination + (e.Location.Y - mousePoint.Y);
                if (newy < -90)
                    newy = -90;
                if (newy > 90)
                    newy = 90;

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Inclination = newy;

                mousePoint = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you code.

Here it is in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub chart_drag(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles embChartTitrations_A_B.MouseMove
        Dim intY As Integer

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            If pointStart = Nothing Then
                pointStart = e.Location
            Else

                intY = embChartTitrations_A_B.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Rotation - Math.Round((e.Location.X - pointStart.X) / 5)
                If intY < -180 Then intY = -180
                If intY > 180 Then intY = 180

                embChartTitrations_A_B.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Rotation = intY



                intY = embChartTitrations_A_B.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Inclination + Math.Round((e.Location.Y - pointStart.Y) / 5)
                If intY < -90 Then intY = -90
                If intY > 90 Then intY = 90

                embChartTitrations_A_B.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Inclination = intY

                pointStart = e.Location
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

(I've divided the mouse movement by 5 as I felt it allowed more precise rotation of the chart)

Thanks

Kristian

Answer (score 0):

Small corrections and optimizations to Ken's C# sample (which otherwise isn't bad, I voted +1):

```
private Point _mousePos;
private void chart_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
    if (!_mousePos.IsEmpty)
    {
        var style = chart.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle;
        style.Rotation = Math.Min(180, Math.Max(-180,
            style.Rotation - (e.Location.X - _mousePos.X)));
        style.Inclination = Math.Min(90, Math.Max(-90,
            style.Inclination + (e.Location.Y - _mousePos.Y)));
    }
    _mousePos = e.Location;
}
```